# javascript async help async.timesLimit

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, axios

I'm trying to scrape a site asynchronously but without doing 500 request at a time but 3 at a time

```
module.exports.siteRequest = function(n,userInput) {
  payload["numb"]=n
  axios.post(URL, payload, { headers: headers }).then(res => {
      console.log("id",id)
      console.log(res.data)
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log("err");
    });
};


async.timesLimit(500,2, function(n, next) {
          siteRequest(n,data)
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the `.next` function in `timesLimit` in order to signal to the `timesLimit` iterator that the next item should be requested. For example, the following code will make 10 total requests, with no more than 2 requests at a time:

```js
const makePromise = () => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 500)).then(() => {
  console.log('resolving');
});
function siteRequest() {
  console.log('initializing');
  return makePromise();
};


async.timesLimit(10,2, function(n, next) {
  siteRequest().then(next);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/async/2.6.1/async.min.js"></script>
```

For your code, make sure to `return` the `Promise` returned by `axios` as well, so you can chain off of it in your `timesLimit`. You can also use dot notation, which is preferable to bracket notation when possible:

```
module.exports.siteRequest = function(n,userInput) {
  payload.numb = n
  return axios.post(URL, payload, { headers: headers }).then(res => {
    console.log("id",id)
    console.log(res.data)
  })
    .catch(e => {
    console.log("err");
  });
};
async.timesLimit(500,2, function(n, next) {
  siteRequest(n,data).then(next);
});
```